# Generalised Estimating Equation (GEE) vs. Recurrent Neural Network (RNN)

Tags: statistics, neural-networks

Has anyone looked into or know what is the difference between a GEE model and an RNN model in terms of what these two models are doing? Apart from the differences in structure of these two models where GEE is an extension of Generalised Linear Model (GLM) and RNN is of a neural network structure, it seems to me that these 2 models are doing the same thing?

Comment: A recurrent neural network is a sequence $Y_{n+1} = f(A Y_n+b)$ where $A$ is a matrix and $Y_n$ is a vector and $f$ is a component-wise function such as $f(Z)_j = \tanh(Z_j)$. Why do you think GLM-GEE is about that ?

Comment: Thanks. GEE is a glm model built to incorporate correlation within “clusters” in a dataset. These “clusters” can be things like say the reaction of a patient to a drug over time, and you can have however many different patients in your dataset (ie. each row in your dataset represents a patient, and each patient can be repeated in the rows to represent the “over time” component). Since “clusters” in GEE can be things like “over time”, there is a sequence structure in GEE, just like in RNN, so both models are doing the same thing?

Comment: I'd say you can mix the generative model RNN and GLM to obtain a stochastic RNN (ie. $f(AY_n+b)$ tells the pdf of $Y_{n+1}$ instead of giving it directly) but its parameter estimation, assuming you are given all the $Y_n$, will be less robust than for GLM, because your drawings are far from independent. It is completely different from the spirit of RNNs where you are not given the $Y_n$, only $Y_0$ and a few entries of a few $Y_n$.

Comment: For the drug setting then hidden Markov model and Kalman filter might help too

Comment: Thanks. I thought in RNN you must be given the full set of  to train the model, similar to [this](https://m.imgur.com/gallery/JAl6uoN)